# React select npm onBlur function returns An error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Hi everyone I am having an issue with the react-select onBlur function, I did a lot of research and looked into relevant git issues but still couldn't find an answer. OnBlur function does not get the selected values, the value in onBlur is shown undefined.  if the answer available please suggest me. Thanks for the help

Codesanbox Link for reference:

[image: Edit strange-sun-uojxs]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();
  const options = [
    {
      label: "first option",
      value: 1
    },
    {
      label: "second option",
      value: 2
    },
    {
      label: "third option",
      value: 3
    }
  ];

  const onSelect = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
  };
  const onBlurValue = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        value={options.label}
        options={options}
        onChange={onSelect}
        blurInputOnSelect
        onBlur={onBlurValue}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code (check out the comments):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {  
  const [value, setValue] = useState();
  const options = [
    {
      label: "first option",
      value: 1
    },
    {
      label: "second option",
      value: 2
    },
    {
      label: "third option",
      value: 3
    }
  ];

  // destructuring the object to get 'value' property
  // (the passed object looks like { label, value } )
  const onSelect = ({value}) => {
    // here the 'value' variable is being set
    console.debug("selected value:", value )
    setValue(value);
  };

  // destructuring event object to get 'target' property
  const onBlurValue = ({target}) => {
    console.log("onBlur target value:", target.value);
    // the value is not updated yet, so it holds the previously set value
    console.log("onBlur value:", value || "undefined");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Current value is: {value || "undefined" }
      <Select
        // the value prop does nothing here
        // value={options.label}
        options={options}
        onChange={onSelect}
        blurInputOnSelect
        onBlur={onBlurValue}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit relaxed-ellis-y1z2d]

As @a.mola said - the `setValue` hook is asynchronous, and the `value` variable isn't updated yet when the `onBlur` event fires, so it holds the previously set value.

I'm not sure about what are you trying to achieve within the `onBlur` event, it may not be the right place to do it.

If you need to output the `value` somehow - you can do so within the `return` part (as is done in code above).

If you need to validate the `value` or do something based on its newly selected value - you can do so within the `onSelect` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an instance variable to store the selected value (maybe not the best solution but it should work)

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();
  const valueRef = useRef();  

  const onSelect = value => {
    valueRef.current = value;
    setValue(value);
  };

  const onBlurValue = () => {
    console.log(valueRef.current);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        value={value}
        options={options}
        onChange={onSelect}
        blurInputOnSelect
        onBlur={onBlurValue}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem with this solution is that you store the selected value in two places (the state variable and the reference instance variable).

The question is, why do you need the get the selected value inside the onBlur handler ? The onChange handler might be sufficient in your case, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

**That might be a problem with React of that version, or conflicting between `react-select` and that specific version of `react`**

Try to upgrade both `react` and `react-dom` to the latest version (17.0.2) and `react-select` to 4.3.1 solve the issue.

Working Example:

[image: Edit distracted-wright-cp0ws]

Comment: I am update version but It not working @Ryan Le

Comment: Can I see your code? Have you checked my codesanbox?

Comment: OnBlur I want to get the selected value But it not working in your sandbox I consoled it show some undefined value  Thanks for the help @Ryan Le

Comment: Oh! I see, I thought you were mentioned about the error only.

Answer (score 0):

The prop `blurInputOnSelect` you pass to the `Select` component, removes focus from the Component after the value has changed and since [`useState`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) and [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) are asynchronous, the value isn't updated immediately. That is why the value logged to the console is `undefined`.

The solution will be to remove the `blurInputOnSelect` prop from the `Select` component

[image: Edit bitter-sun-s81se]